# Meaning of "tokens" in pyLDAvis

Tags: python, lda, topic-modeling, pyldavis

I created an LDA visualization using pyLDAvis and was wondering what "token" means in the title of the bar graph (i.e., Topic 3 (14% of tokens)). I read the pyLDAvis documentation, but could not find an explanation. Does this mean that 14% of all the documents in the corpus fit into this topic or does it have to do with the distribution of words?

Thank you for the help.

[Example bar graph that I generated using pyLDAvis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV6k9.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi there - I read the pyLDAvis documentation and did a Google search, but was not getting a consistent answer. Now that I think about it, I do not think the percentage represents the percent of documents in the corpus that are in the topic, but rather the percentage of words in the bag of words. Just wanted to get confirmation if I am interpreting that correctly. Thank you.

Comment: Any insight you have here is appreciated. Thanks.